# I have a counter to track the number or rounds, but I cannot figure out how to end the game after hitting that number

Tags: javascript

```html
  <!DOCTYPE <!doctype html>
  <html class="no-js" lang="">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
          <title>Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock</title>
          <meta name="description" content="">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
          <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
          <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
  
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
          
      </head>
      <body>
          <header>
      <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock</h1>
      <div class="scoreboard">
        <div id="round-label" class="badgeRound">Round:</div>
        <div id="player-label" class="badge">Player</div>
        <div id="computer-label" class="badge">Computer</div>
        <div id = "scores-section">
        <span id="player-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      </header>

      <div class="result">
        <p>Select Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock</p>
        </div>

      <div class="choices">
        <div id="rock" class="choice">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/B2vtbGV.png" alt="">
       </div >
       <div id="paper" class="choice">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ysz5uYB.png" alt="">
      </div >
      <div id="scissors" class="choice">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bx6LLDK.png" alt="">
     </div >
     <div id="lizard" class="choice">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8nyBB4R.png" alt="">
    </div >
    <div id="spock" class="choice">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/E0mrqVJ.png" alt="">
    </div >
       </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

I tried to build upon Rock Paper Scissors and have everything working as I want, but I cannot get it to end the game when you hit that number.

There is a prompt to ask the user how many rounds he/she wishes to play.  Also, there is a Round counter that shows you the amount entered.

I've added a function to end the game "if (currRound > numRounds)" but it exceeds that amount.

```html
let name = prompt('What is your name?','Player');
name = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
let numOfRounds = prompt('How many rounds should we play?',11);
let numRounds = (numOfRounds != 0) ? numOfRounds : 11;
alert('Good luck, ' + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + '! ' + '\n\nWe are playing ' + numRounds + ' rounds.');
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let currRound = 0;
const playerScore_span = document.getElementById("player-score");
const computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
const scoreboard_div = document.querySelector("scoreboard");
const result_p = document.querySelector(".result >p");
const player_label_div = document.querySelector("#player-label");
const computer_label_div = document.querySelector('#computer-label');
const round_label_div = document.getElementById("round-label");
const rock_div = document.getElementById("rock");
const paper_div = document.getElementById("paper");
const scissors_div = document.getElementById("scissors");
const lizard_div = document.getElementById("lizard");
const spock_div = document.getElementById("spock");

const getPlayerName = () => {
  player_label_div.innerHTML = `${name}`;
}

const getComputerChoice = () => {
  const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper','Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock'];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length); 
  return choices[randomNumber];
}

const winRound = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
  playerScore++;
  playerScore_span.innerHTML = playerScore;
  const colorMyWord = `${name}: `.fontcolor("#c9b31e");
  const playerWinsHand = " wins! ".fontcolor("#3300ff");
  result_p.innerHTML = `${colorMyWord}${playerWinsHand} <br> ${colorMyWord} ${playerChoice}<br> Computer: ${computerChoice}.`;
  player_label_div.innerHTML = `${name}`;
  currRound++;
  round_label_div.innerHTML = `Round: ${currRound} / ${numRounds}`;
}


const loseRound = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
  computerScore++;
  playerScore_span.innerHTML = playerScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const colorCompWord = " Computer".fontcolor("#c9b31e");
  result_p.innerHTML = `The ${colorCompWord} wins!<br> ${colorCompWord}: ${computerChoice}<br> ${name}: ${playerChoice}`
  currRound++;
  round_label_div.innerHTML = `Round: ${currRound} / ${numRounds}`;
}

const draw = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
  const colorDrawWord = `It's a tie!`.fontcolor("#ff4000");
  result_p.innerHTML = `${colorDrawWord}<br>${name}: ${playerChoice}<br>Computer: ${computerChoice}`;
  player_label_div.innerHTML = `${name}`;
  currRound++;
  round_label_div.innerHTML = `Round: ${currRound} / ${numRounds}`;
}
 const game = (playerChoice) => {
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  switch (playerChoice + computerChoice) {
    case "ScissorsPaper":
    case "ScissorsLizard":
    case "PaperRock":
    case "PaperSpock":
    case "RockScissors":
    case "RockLizard":
    case "LizardPaper":
    case "LizardSpock":
    case "SpockScissors":
    case "SpockRock":
      winRound(playerChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case "ScissorsRock":
    case "ScissorsSpock":
    case "PaperScissors":
    case "PaperLizard":
    case "RockPaper":
    case "RockSpock":
    case "LizardScissors":
    case "LizardRock":
    case "SpockPaper":
    case "SpockLizard":
      loseRound(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    break;
    case "RockRock":
    case "PaperPaper":
    case "ScissorsScissors":
    case "LizardLizard":
    case "SpockSpock":
      draw(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    break;
  }
}

const main = () => {
  
  rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("Rock");
  })
  paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("Paper");
  })
  scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("Scissors");
  })
  lizard_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("Lizard");
  })
  spock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("Spock");
  })
}

main();
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML code to your code snippet?

Comment: There are many places you could put the game counter logic. It entirely depends on how you want the game to behave? Do you want them to still be able to select an option and just get an error/message? Do you want the page to change? Display results?

Comment: I want them to have an option to retry, if they wish.  Otherwise, just return to the game.

Comment: Your round counting logic looks off. Surely if you want to eg. play one round, upon completion of the first round, you're not on `Round: 1 / 1`

Comment: It displays as Round:: 1/1 when I am playing to 1.  Sorry Adam, I don't understand.

Comment: Your initial condition was `if (currRound > numRounds)`, which makes sense if `currRound` actually is "current round" (where you start on round 1), but it actually represents "completed rounds", so it would have played one more round than was intended (hence why the answer has `==` instead)

Comment: Thank you for explaining that @AdamPalaniuk.  Now i understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `if` statement at the end of `game`:

```
if (currRound == numRounds) {
    alert("That's all the rounds you wanted to play! Game over!");
    // Display score etc.
}
```

(also note that you should parse `numRounds` into a number when you get it from the `prompt`.)

Comment: Thank you Jack!  I was placing it at the bottom of the code.